# How do you use the checked value of a checkbox in a sidebar to start a gs function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I'm new around here. I'm working in an App Script add-on and I was wondering how do you use the checked value of a checkbox in a sidebar to start a particular GS function?

Here is the example HTML of the sidebar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<link href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css"
     rel="stylesheet"> 
</head> 
  <body>
<div class="sidebar">
<p>Please select the checkbox you need</p>
    <form>
    <div class="block form-group">
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX1">
    <label for="CHECKBOX1">CHECKBOX1</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX2">
    <label for="CHECKBOX2">CHECKBOX2</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX3">
    <label for="CHECKBOX3">CHECKBOX3</label></div>
          <div class="block">
        <button class="action" id="useGsFunctions">Start Functions</button>
         </div>
         </form>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I would like to call, when the useGsFunctions is pressed, the GS function1 if the checkbox1 is true and/or the GS function2 if the checkbox2 is selected. But how do you do that?

Thanks in advance for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <link href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css"
 rel="stylesheet"> 
 <script>
  function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("CHECKBOX1").checked){
        //Call your GS function 1
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("CHECKBOX2").checked){
        //Call your GS function 2
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("CHECKBOX3").checked){
        //Call your GS function 3
    }
  }

 </script>
 </head> 
 <body>
     <div class="sidebar">
       <p>Please select the checkbox you need</p>
       <form>
       <div class="block form-group">
          <div><input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX1">
               <label for="CHECKBOX1">CHECKBOX1</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX2">
               <label for="CHECKBOX2">CHECKBOX2</label></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" id="CHECKBOX3">
               <label for="CHECKBOX3">CHECKBOX3</label></div>
          <div class="block">
               <button type = "button" class="action" id="useGsFunctions" onclick="check()">Start Functions</button>
     </div>
     </form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```